# Third order linear differential equation and Painlevé II solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

Consider the solution to the Painlevé II equation on $\mathbb{R}$

$$q''=2q^3+rq$$

with the boundary condition $q(r)\sim_{r\to +\infty} \mathrm{Ai}(r)$ and consider the function $f$ such that for $r\in \mathbb{R}$,

$$f(r)=\cosh\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_r^{+\infty} \mathrm{d} s \, q(s)\right)$$

We have that $f$ verifies the third order differential equation

$$f'''+P(r) f' +Q(r) f =0 \qquad \qquad (\mathcal{E})$$

with

$$\begin{cases}
P(r)=-\frac{9}{4}q(r)^2-r\\
Q(r)=\frac{1}{6}P'(r)+\frac{1}{6}
\end{cases}$$

My question is the following, if one is given the differential equation $(\mathcal{E})$ with the proper boundary condition, is there a standard technique / change of variable to find back the expression of the function $f$ ?